# How to get from the console (Windows, powershell, a specific string

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm pinging the server 8.8.8.8, and in java I need to write exactly the value "Average = .. ms" into the variable. This outputs 2 lines

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | %{ $_.Split(',')[2]}
```

How can I display only the average value (namely, the number, without the word "Average")

Comment: Are you referring to the latency?

Comment: Average execution time, just a number, how can I do this?

Comment: Mathias's answer should cover that

Comment: FYI - the `.PingReplyDetails` property returned by `Test-NetConnection` shows the average ping time. in my case, that was 24 or 25 ms when hitting `8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-match` operator to capture the number:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | ForEach-Object {
  if($_ -match 'Average = (\d+)'){
    $Matches[1]
  }
}
```

The `$Matches` automatic variable will be populated with any values captured by the regex pattern you most recently used to get a successful match with the `-match` operator, so `$Matches[1]` will contain whatever `(\d+)` matched (in this case, the digits immediately after `Average =` ).

Comment: Do keep in mind that if you ping to something that never pings back this will return nothing.

Comment: @francisco.l, neither would an echo request to something that won't reply.